# Chrome url match patterns

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I can't seem to get the "?" char to match a question mark in a url.

So essentially

```
"matches": [ "http://www.google.com/search?* ],
```

will not match

```
"http://www.google.com/search?cx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asdf"
```

Also,

```
"matches" : [ "http://www.google.com/search*asdf" ],
```

doesn't match

```
"http://www.google.com/search?aq=f&cx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=asdf"
```

---

This has led me to believe that chrome doesn't consider anything after the "?". Is this right?

Comment: I plan on injecting through the background page where I can call the one of many string methods, like indexOf, and use regular expressions. The equivalent behavior of content_scripts is performed using chrome.tabs.insertCSS and chrome.tabs.executeScript for those curious.

Comment: It's possible that Chrome is treating `?` like regex. Try escaping it by doing `\?`. Also `*` is a regex special character, so your example containing it would only find strings with zero or more h's in "search" followed by "asdf".

Comment: The docs suggest kinda suggest the urls aren't matched beyond a "?" http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: \? generates an "Invalid escape sequence" error when you try and load the extension, I also tried encoding it as %3F, which didn't work.

Comment: This isn't javascript; it's some special chrome extension, right?

Comment: This link is fairly clear that you can't look at parameters (http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/match_patterns.html).  But you could have code at the start of your extension that does nothing if a match is not found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take out the question mark, according to the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/develop/concepts/match-patterns):

```
"matches": [ "http://www.google.com/search* ],
```

That will match the request parameters as well.

Comment: Yeah, I've concluded that even more specific pattern matching cannot be performed, even the `exclude_globs`, `exclude_matches`, and `include_blogs` don't seem to go into the GET params after the "?"

Comment: Yea, unfortunately the pattern matching in Chrome Extensions is weak and really simple. If you want to do more advanced matching, you should do that within your content script with real regular expressions. That is what I do for a couple of my extensions.

Comment: So it's only possible to match against urls in the manifest? Can we use match patterns on `chrome.tabs.onUpdated`? The doc says it's possible but I don't know how: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query

Answer (score 1):

As an update: using `?` in MatchPatterns is allowed. The [current docs for the path state that](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns)

> ```
> <path> := '/' <any chars>
> ```

Where

> In the path section, each '*' matches 0 or more characters.

See usage at https://github.com/serv-inc/hider/blob/master/addon/manifest.json#L24.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to show us the code you're using to do this matching.  If you're using a string search function that takes a regular expression, then you have to escape all regular expression characters if you want them to be searched for as a normal character.

To escape a regular expression character, you would precede it with a backslash like this:

```
"matches": [ "http://www.google.com/search\?* ],
```

If you don't want to mess with regular expressions, you can use a non-regex search like `.indexOf()` and you won't have to worry about this.

Comment: this is standard content_scripts pattern matching in the manifest.json file for chrome extensions. This is all the real code there is. I'm not doing anything in the background page, yet.

Comment: @Devin G Rhode - Did you bother to tell any of us that this was standard content_scripts pattern matching for an extension in your question?  How are we supposed to know that?  I'm wondering why the downvote as this contains an accurate answer.